# Error el enviar datos de un formulario HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

estoy tratando de hacer funcionar un formulario HTML, PHP pero al momento de abrirlo en el localhost y enviarlo me aparece esto y no se como solucionarlo, tambien probe en mandarlo directamente desde mi HTML sin abrir el localhost y me aparece esto, les dejo el codigo html y php para que lo puedan ver.

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" class="form_contact">
        <h2>Envia un mensaje</h2>
        <div class="user_info">
            <label for="names">Nombres *</label>
            <input type="text" id="names" name="nombre" required>

            <label for="phone">Telefono / Celular</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="telefono">

            <label for="email">Correo electronico *</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="correo" required>

            <label for="mensaje">Mensaje *</label>
            <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" required></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Mensaje" id="btnSend">
        </div>
    </form>
```

```
    <?php  

// Llamando a los campos
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

$header = 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

// Datos para el correo
$destinatario = "aca va mi email pero lo saco por las dudas jaj";
$asunto = "Contacto desde nuestra web";

$carta = "De: $nombre \n";
$carta .= "Correo: $correo \n";
$carta .= "Telefono: $telefono \n";
$carta .= "Mensaje: $mensaje";

// Enviando Mensaje
mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta, $header);
header('Location:index.html');

?>
```

[image: Segundo error HTML sin LOCALHOST]
[image: Error en LOCALHOST]

Comment: en localhost no funciona la salida de mails, lo Tenes que probar para ver si realmente funciona en tu servidor web

Comment: @Daniel lo que afirmas no es correcto, en `localhost` si se puede enviar email.
El detalle que tienes es que al parecer estas agregando la ruta con `https` al inicio y si no lo tienes configurado debes usar solo `http`

Comment: Al parecer el método POST está deshabilitado en el servidor, es lo que significa el [error 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) que estás recibiendo.